# How can I get my question answered instead of being autodeleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

This is a followup question to [this older question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9492/404182) about [my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/444958/404182).

At first being way too broad, the question was promptly closed as opinion-based/needs more focus. After quite some time of editing I finally got the question into an answerable state and reopened. I also got upvotes, but not enough to bring the score to 0. This is the second time now I have flagged for a moderator to undelete the question after being automatically deleted by the Community user.

Is there any further advice for the question so I can get the question answered and permanently not deleted? What can I do to finish 'redeeming' the question? I would still like an answer and just re-asking the question by copying the current revision into the ask question page seems a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now the question is open and has a non-negative score.  Reading it myself, I feel that you did a good job of explaining the various potential advantages and disadvantages of each approach and you did a good job of asking specifically what kind of answer you are looking for.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem like you have gotten a good answer, however I can't specifically help you with that.

A good question is not guaranteed a good answer unfortunately. It might mean that the question just hasn't gotten good attention, or it might mean that there is fundamentally no good answer to your question.  While I don't consider myself an "expert" in C/C++, I know enough about it and cross OS software development that my intuition has me leaning towards the latter.  It seems that a factual objective truth or best practice probably doesn't exist here, and this specific problem has enough potential caveats, risks, or architecture considerations that it is likely highly specific to a given use case or scenario needs.  An objective answer to this question would look something like what you have already added into your question, which is a set of criteria and considerations that should be weighed against to arrive at the most sensible decision for your problem specifically.

In other words, a good answer to your question is likely to evaluation criteria that would lead to the best solution to your specific use case as a software engineer.